# Limit the calls to an R function in case of warning

Tags: r, exception, mapply

I have a function foo:

```
foo<-function(x,y,z){
    {
      some initial R code
    }
    eresult<-tryCatch(expr= eresult<-eclat(),
        warning = function(w){
            writelog(paste(w),logfile)
            result<-eclat()
            return(result)
        },
        error=function(e){
            writelog(paste(e),logfile)
        })
    }
```

I am calling foo in loop using mapply over two columns of a data.frame df and one fixed argument "db_credential" for parameter z.

```
df<-data.frame(a=(1,2),b=c(2,3))
tryCatch(expr=mapply(FUN=foo,df$a,df$b,"db_credential"),
         warning=function(w){writelog(paste(w),logfile)},
         error=function(e){writelog(paste(e),logfile)})
```

On execution of this set of code, the eclat function throws a warning due to some choice of parameters for the function call of eclat. So **foo** is being called **4 times**.

Is there a way by which I can **restrict** the call to **foo** only **2 times** [to avoid the execution of "some initial R code" which involves **fetching data from database and it's transformation**] and yet handle all the warnings and errors.

I just want that the **eclat** function should be called again with the same parameters to produce the output rather than the control being thrown to the warning part of **mapply** call.

Comment: There is already a `tryCatch` statement in foo(). You shouldn't use another one arround the mapply. Replace `tryCatch(expr=mapply(` with `mapply(...` only. Is "some intitial R code" common to all parameters df$a and df$b? Also you might want to checkt the dplyr pacakge and its `group_by(a,b) %>% do()` statement.

Comment: The tryCatch around mapply is to catch the warnings/errors in the remaining part of the foo function. The arguments passed through df$a and df$b are used to create distinct queries to fetch data from database.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at `purrr::safely`, which converts functions to store both the result and possible warnings and errors.

Comment: So far what I have figured out here is that the issue is occurring because of the mapply call. When it is replaced by a for loop, the code runs only two times.

Comment: One of the issue was that the warning that eclat is throwing is not suppressed when it is called again inside the warning function. To suppress the warning from eclat I used the suppressWarnings() from base R.